# $\frac{d}{dz}(-\frac{i}{8}\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1})+\frac{i}{32}\sinh(4\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1})=z^{2}\sqrt{1-z^{2}}$True if?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Under what conditions is it true that

$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(-\frac{i}{8}\operatorname{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}\right)+\frac{i}{32}\sinh\left(4\operatorname{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}\right)\right)\right)=z^{2}\sqrt{1-z^{2}}$$ $\tag1$

Can I choose the principal square root for every square root?

(I'm fairly certain the equation is false if the principal square root is not chosen)

Can I choose the principal value for every $\operatorname{Log}$?

I haven't made any progress toward answering this specific question about necessary conditions but I have worked out a (possibly erroneous) way to demonstrate that some version of the statement is true.

Using $z=\cosh\theta$:
$$\int z^{2}\sqrt{1-z^{2}}dz=\int \cosh^{2}\left(\theta\right)\sqrt{1-\cosh^{2}\left(\theta\right)}\sinh\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{i}{4}\int \left(\frac{\cosh\left(4\theta\right)-1}{2}\right)d\theta$$
$$=-\frac{i}{8}\operatorname{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}\right)+\frac{i}{32}\sinh\left(4\operatorname{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}\right)\right)+C$$

I'm well aware that I might have absolutely zero justification for using $\operatorname{arcosh}(z)=\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})$ so I'm very unsure about this.

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29d%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29dz%5C%28125%29%5Cleft%5C%2840%29-%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29i%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%298%5C%28125%29%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29z%2B%5Csqrt%5C%28123%29Power%5Bz%2C%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%5D-1%5C%28125%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29%2B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29i%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%2932%5C%28125%29%5Csinh%5Cleft%5C%2840%294%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29z%2B%5Csqrt%5C%28123%29Power%5Bz%2C%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%5D-1%5C%28125%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29) does seem to confirm that (1) is true but I cannot be sure that Wolfram is being sufficiently careful about branches.